# Is there a Postgis SQL Coding Style Guidelines?

Tags: postgis, coding-style

Most programming languages have Coding styles. Some have defined standards, other have just some code of conduct that the majority of programmers follow.

Standard coding styles are have obvious [benefits](http://www.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/10-benefits-of-using-coding-standards-to-software-development-team-312610.html), in gis.stackexchange itself, it would help people better understand both questions and answers.

From some "googling", there are some reference to Coding Styles for SQL, although they are not consensual:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118288/sql-coding-style-guide
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522356/what-sql-coding-standard-do-you-follow
- http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-layout-and-beautification/

While this SQL coding styles can be used for Postgis, my question is if there is a Postgis\SQL coding style to handle its functions, or at least some common practices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no style guide for PostGIS SQL, and as with other languages everyone has their own quirks, but here's my general rules, which I think lead to more readable results:

- Use caps for SQL keywords (SELECT, INSERT, FROM, WITH, AND, OR)
- Use mixed case for functions (ST_Distance, Abs, Strlen, ST_Intersects)
- Prefer JOIN syntax over putting join conditions in the WHERE clause
- Prefer WITH syntax over sub-queries

I'm sure there's some reasonable rules for writing PL/PgSQL too, but I don't do that myself.